# Django queryset retrieve nothing but the instance exist

Tags: python, django

I'm facing an issue with Django that I have never seen. When I try to make a query to filter a user the result is empty, but the user really exists. I don't know if Django has some issue when the database is hugue. I don't know how to start to understand how can I fix it.

Here is an example copied directly from my shell:

```
In [18]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User
In [19]: User.objects.get(pk=22247).email
Out[19]: u'person@example.com'
In [20]: User.objects.filter(email='person@example.com')
Out[20]: []
```

How can it be possible? Somebody can give some guidance to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Usefull data:

- Im using Python 2.7.14 and Django 1.8.16
- Also this bug doesn't happen all the time, sometimes it retrieve the instance correctly but the 80% of the queries retrieve nothing.

Comment: Could be an encoding issue of the string containing `@`. Is it only for the email field? What if you query by username etc.?

Comment: By username it works, but its a weird behaviour to fail by email. We work with utf-8 and the @ is a common symbol used in several encodings. The curious thing here is that filtering by email the same user sometimes fails, sometimes works.

Comment: Maybe look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/unicode/#conversion-functions) and try using `email=smart_text('person@example.com')`

Comment: Hi ascripter, I tried with smart_text but it doesn't work, it returns an empty queryset.